# Usage Class type as a key in Java DSL Payload Type Router

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

Is it possible to specify real Java `Class` as a key in [Payload Type Router](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-routing-chapter.html#router-implementations-payloadtyperouter)?

Currently I must do convertion from `Class` to `String` manually

```
...
.<Object, String>route(p -> p.getClass().getName(), // transform raw payload to mapping string key
        m -> m.suffix("Channel")
                // route to path1Channel 
                .channelMapping(Integer.class.getTypeName(), "path1")
                // route to path2Channel
                .channelMapping(String.class.getTypeName(), "path2")
                // route to path3Channel
                .channelMapping(Doulbe.class.getTypeName(), "path3")
)
...
```

but I would expect smth less cumbersome

```
...
.<Object, Class>route(p -> p.getClass(),
        m -> m.suffix("Channel")
                .channelMapping(Integer.class, "path1")
                .channelMapping(String.class, "path2")
                .channelMapping(Doulbe.class, "path3")
)
...
```

or even like this

```
...
.payloadTypeRouter(
        m -> m.suffix("Channel")
                .channelMapping(Integer.class, "path1")
                .channelMapping(String.class, "path2")
                .channelMapping(Doulbe.class, "path3")
)
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, Andrey, it isn't possible. Agreed.

The same is valid for the `ErrorMessageExceptionTypeRouter`.

From one hand all routers implement `MappingMessageRouterManagement`, where you can see that only `String` is valid as a key.

From another - you always can configure the target `AbstractMessageRouter` implementation (`PayloadTypeRouter`) as a `@Bean` and refer it from the `.route()` EIP-method.

And finally: feel free to contribute those gaps: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl/wiki

I'd call them like `.payloadTypeRoute()` and `.errorRoute()`.

Thank you for pointing that out!